# Centering a rollover button part of a division that has a background. CSS

Tags: css, button, background-image, center, rollover

I have the following element:

```
<div class="menubar">
    <a class="homebutton" href="mydomain.com/home"></a> 
</div>
```

Using this style:

```
.menubar {
    text-align:center;
    background-image:url(/img/menubar_background.png);
}

.homebutton
{
    display: block;
    width: 139px;
    height: 23px;
    background: url("/img/home_button_rollover.png") no-repeat 0 0;
}

.homebutton:hover
{ 
    background-position: 0 -23px;
}
```

What I am trying to achieve is to have the menubar center it's content and the buttons is a CSS-rollover. The problem is that the button, using this exact code stays aligned to the left instead of being center.

**Solved (j08691):**

```
.homebutton
{
    display: inline-block;
    margin:0 auto;
    width: 139px;
    height: 23px;
    background: url("/img/home_button_rollover.png") no-repeat 0 0;
}
```

Works: http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/WdQfk/1/

Comment: And the problem you're having is...?

Comment: @j08691 The button stays all the way to the left.

Comment: maybe create a quick fiddle so everyone is looking at same thing. might help expedite fix for you.

Comment: @origin1tech http://jsfiddle.net/fBGXT/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `margin:0 auto;` to `.homebutton`.

To center a block element it has to have a width (you have that) and you need to set the left and right margin to auto e.g. `0 auto`;

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/WdQfk/)**

Comment: If I put other buttons they end up under each other all in the center instead of being side by side; any ideas?

Comment: Try `display:inline-block;` instead of `display:block;`. http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/WdQfk/1/

Comment: my .02 I like to use this cross-browsers inline-block => *display:inline; display:-moz-inline-stack;
display:inline-block;
zoom:1;

Comment: @origin1tech What's the difference?

Comment: it works better on multiple browsers. some browsers may have difficulty with display:inline-block;

Comment: @origin1tech - specifically, what browsers are you referring to? My solution works all the way back to IE5.